# The python plotly: PlotlyError

Tags: python, plotly

I am learning the python plotly at https://plot.ly/python/offline/
And when I try this example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py 
fig = py.get_figure('https://plot.ly/~jackp/8715', raw=True)
iplot(fig)
```

the answer gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PlotlyError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-71d04f672671> in <module>()
      1 import plotly.plotly as py
      2 
----> 3 fig = py.get_figure('https://plot.ly/~jackp/8715', raw=True)
      4 iplot(fig)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.pyc in get_figure(file_owner_or_url, file_id, raw)
    407                 "'{1}'."
    408                 "\nRun help on this function for more information."
--> 409                 "".format(url, plotly_rest_url))
    410         head = plotly_rest_url + "/~"
    411         file_owner = url.replace(head, "").split('/')[0]

PlotlyError: Because you didn't supply a 'file_id' in the call, we're assuming you're trying to snag a figure from a url. You supplied the url, 'https://plot.ly/~jackp/8715', we expected it to start with 'https://plotly.your-company.com'.
Run help on this function for more information.
```

I don't know where the error is, and I think it may be the url https://plotly.your-company.com is broken.

Comment: As it says immediately above the example - `You need to provide credentials to download figures`.

Comment: Thank you.I try your advice but it didnt work either.how do u modify it

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [recommended](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/) way to get the credentials file. Reading fully through the examples when following a tutorial always helps, setting up your environment properly is important.

1. Go [here](https://plot.ly/feed/) and create an account
2. Go [here](https://plot.ly/settings/api) and get an API key
3. Type this into your code before you do try to get the figure (must import plotly as well as plotly.plotly):

`plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='username-from-step-1', api_key='key-you-copied-from-step-2')`

This line will grant you access

Edit: `iplot(fig)` only works on some setups, if you get a new error. Try replacing the line with `py.plot(fig)`

Answer (score 0):

`plotly.plotly` functionality moved under `chart_studio.Plotly` Library which require API key and username to plot it

instead of that follow the below steps to plot any graph which consists of dict object

```
import plotly.io as pio

pio.show(fig)
```